# Keycloak ID token doesnt contain "group" information

Tags: keycloak

I am using a javax filter which gets a HttpRequest from keycloak server if the user has successfully authenticated. 
From the request I was able to get the Id token and on decoding this `group` name is missing from the id token.

How to map the group name information in id token ?

Comment: Below is my decode id token claim
`{
  "jti": "727a9f7a-1fae-4341-b171-b852d4406039",
  "exp": 1553066567,
  "nbf": 0,
  "iat": 1553066267,
  "iss": "http://10.75.145.38:8665/auth/realms/spark-acl-http",
  "aud": "spark-driver",
  "sub": "77f07a4b-ac91-4f9a-a66c-4c5312d28a0c",
  "typ": "ID",
  "azp": "spark-driver",
  "auth_time": 1553066265,
  "session_state": "a7a6e543-2f59-4787-8f4c-30c45ea1ea84",
  "acr": "1",
  "email_verified": false,
  "preferred_username": "ajay"
}
`

Answer (score 4):

Fixed. Had to add a new group mapper for my client under mapper tab

Comment: Hey, can you please share mapper settings
ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64334364/get-azure-groups-information-in-keycloak-id-token