# Get Azure groups information in keycloak id_token

Tags: azure-active-directory, keycloak

I have registered Azure active directory as an identity provider in the Keycloack server.
I am getting groups array in azure's id_token and it looks like:

```
{
     aud: "https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/scratchservice",
     iss: "https://sts.windows.net/b9411234-09af-49c2-b0c3-653adc1f376e/",
     iat: 1416968588,
     nbf: 1416968588,
     exp: 1416972488,
     ver: "1.0",
     tid: "b9411234-09af-49c2-b0c3-653adc1f376e",
     amr: [
      "pwd"
     ],
     roles: [
      "Admin"
     ],
     oid: "6526e123-0ff9-4fec-ae64-a8d5a77cf287",
     upn: "[hidden email]",
     unique_name: "[hidden email]",
     sub: "yf8C5e_VRkR1egGxJSDt5_olDFay6L5ilBA81hZhQEI",
     family_name: "User",
     given_name: "Sample",
     groups: [
      "0e129f6b-6b0a-4944-982d-f776000632af",
      "323b13b3-1851-4b94-947f-9a4dacb595f4",
      "6e32c250-9b0a-4491-b429-6c60d2ca9a42",
      "f3a161a7-9a58-4e8f-9d47-b70022a07424",
      "8d4c81b2-b1ad-476d-9574-544d155aa6ff",
      "1bf80164-ff24-4866-b19c-6212e5b9a847",
      "76f80127-f2cd-46f4-8c52-8edd8bc749b1",
      "0ba27160-44d0-42b5-b90c-47b3fcc48e35"
     ],
     appid: "b075ddef-0efa-123b-997b-de1337c29185",
     appidacr: "1",
     scp: "user_impersonation",
     acr: "1"
 }
```

In id_token generated by the Keycloak server, there are no groups.
How can I get azure AD groups in keycloack id_token.

Comment: There is a similar issue: https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/getting-groups-from-azure-active-directory-idp/590/13

Comment: @Nitin how you get token from Azure AD and see groups ID ?

Comment: You can check id claims of access_token generated by Azure AD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I resolved this issue by creating a mapper.

Steps:

1. Create Attribute importer type mapper in the identity provider
   [image]
2. Create User attribute type mapper in the client
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

[maartenvds](https://keycloak.discourse.group/u/maartenvds) have a nice solution in [Getting groups from Azure Active Directory IDP](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/getting-groups-from-azure-active-directory-idp/590/2).

I made a `Advanced Claim to Role` in

- Identity providers -> Provider details -> Edit Identity Provider Mapper

I mapped the group UUID in Azure to a Realm role

[image]