# How to map azure object_id in oidc identity provider in keycloak?

Tags: azure, authentication, keycloak, openid-connect

As in the title, anybody knows how to get the object id of the user in oidc identity provider using keycloak?

I cannot figure out a way to add a custom mapper to get the user object id (as on the screenshot) when authenticating againt Azure Active Directory - when the Token (KeycloakAuthenticationToken) is populated to the Rest API, it does contain principal property from keycloak, not azure active directory.

Azure identifier:

[image: Azure identifier]

I have sucessfully created a mapper for the groups - using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64411029/14320246

However there are available as additional attributes, as on screenshot
[Additonal attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjvhp.png), but it is acceptable behaviour for also the oid param.

Answer (score 2):

You should use 'oid' claim in your mapper.
But you have to change default scope at Identity provider -> provider name -> Settings -> Default Scopes to "openid profile"